# Creating independent version of linked file

Tags: visual-studio

In VS I have a single config file that I've added to several projects using "Add as link".

Now I'd like to unlink one of these files and create an independently editable file.

I could just delete from the project and make a new file with the same contents, but if I want to do this for several projects, it will be a pain.

Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 0):

One idea.

Change the config file so there is a section that maps to the project name.
If the section isn't there Use Assembly name ?, Use the "default" current one unamed one.